# Book that helps recognizing underlying mathematical expression of numerical results

Tags: book-recommendation, computational-mathematics, transcendental-numbers, experimental-mathematics

I strongly remember having seen a couple of years ago a huge book that only consisted out of an enormous table over hundreds of pages containing approx. 10⁵ numerical results in ascending order with their symbolic expression as a counterpart, so to help numerical researchers recognising numerical results as mathematically meaningful constants.

Something like

> ...
>
> 0.577215664    |    $\gamma$ ,(Euler-Mascheroni-Constant)
>
> 0.577252312    |    some other expresion
>
> ...

Unfortunately, I can't find the book now - Is anyone out there who can help me finding it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you ever tried using mrob.com/pub/ries/?

Comment: Thank you for this useful hint, @Santiago! I'm surprised I never heard of it before. And although it's much easier to use than any book, I'm still curious to find it..

Comment: Why don't you try using Inverse Symbolic calculators http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standardCalc ? Just tpe the second number : you will get two amazing results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["A Dictionary of Real Numbers"](https://books.google.com/books?id=JGDmBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) by Jonathan and Peter Borwein This book contains "just over $100000$ eight-digit real numbers in the intervalle $[0,1]$. I found it too very useful!

The online counterpart is the [ISC](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html).

Other online substitutes :

- [The inverse symbolic calculator ISC+](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/)
- [RIES](http://mrob.com/pub/ries/index.html)
- the [identify instruction in Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=identify%200.577215)

Comment: That's it, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome @Benjamin W G!